# Create a broadcast service for my website in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, notifications

I have created a dashboard using PHP and Wordpress, the problem i'm facing now is that I need to create an alert or a message when ever a new data has arrived in any users dashboard. So, I need to send the users that are currently online in the dashboard, a notification that a new data has arrived for them.

Whenever a data has been added by me for a particular user, an automatic notification should be shown on the that users screen if he is online. I have created the dashboard, but I don't know how to implement this notification.

In short, I want to create something like a `push` notification inside my website.

Comment: yes, you can. With comet/websockets. If this was your question ;)

Comment: I tried comet, but it doesn't seem to working in local host.. any tutorial or codes I can refer would be really helpful..

Comment: This looks pretty much like what you need...have a look http://socketo.me/docs/push

Answer (score 0):

Use [Atmosphere](https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere) framework for braodcasting any messages. This essentially uses Websockets in the implementation. But its very easy to do.